# Generatingfunctionology 1.6 Stirling Number

Tags: generating-functions, stirling-numbers

I am reading Herbert Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology* these days. And on Page 21, Section 1.6 *Another 2-Variable Case*, I was confused by the operation he did on formula (1.36), which is:

> ...
>
> The partial fraction expansion in question has the form:
>
> $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{a_j}{1-jx}$$
>
> To find the $\alpha$'s, fix $r$, $1\le r \le k$, multiply both sides by $1-rx$, and let $x=\frac{1}{r}$.

As there is such a term $(1-rx)$ on the LHS as part of the divisor, I thought that that implies that $(1-rx)\ne0$, which means $x\ne\frac{1}{r}$. But later on, as mentioned above, the author just let $x=\frac{1}{r}$, which doesn't seems to make sense to me.

My question is why is this operation allowed? Is there any special theorem related to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side of (1)
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots(1-kx)}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{a_j}{1-jx}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is a rational function in the variable $x$ with poles $\frac{1}{r}, 1\leq r\leq k$. The denominator is zero at the poles and the function is not defined there. The right-hand side is the same rational function but written using a partial fraction decomposition.

If we now *fix* an $r$ with $1\leq r\leq k$ and multiply the rational function with $(1-rx)$. We get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-rx}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots(1-kx)}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{a_j(1-rx)}{1-jx}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> In (2) we still have the poles $\frac{1}{r}, 1\leq r\leq k$ as in (1). But we can now *cancel* the term $1-rx$ resulting in
> \begin{align*}
> &\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots(1-(r-1)x)(1-(r+1)x)\cdots (1-kx)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\sum_{j=1}^{r-1}\frac{a_j(1-rx)}{1-jx}+a_r+\sum_{j=r+1}^{k}\frac{a_j(1-rx)}{1-jx}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

The cancellation of the factor $1-rx$ in (3) removes the pole $\frac{1}{r}$, which is a so-called *[removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)*. Contrary to (1) and (2) there is  no harm to evaluate the rational function in (3) at $x=\frac{1}{r}$.

We can now evaluate (3) at $x=\frac{1}{r}$ and get the values $a_r, 1\leq r\leq k$.

Answer (score 0):

Generating functions are often in a class of objects called **formal power series**, where the notion of convergence need not apply (though it often does for small values of $x$). That is to say, you are not actually *evaluating* the series for any value of $x$; it is being treated as an algebraic object in its own right. All you care about are the coefficients for each power of $x$, and this substitution is merely an algebraic trick to find them.

Comment: Thank for the answer! I understand that Generating functions are treated as formal power series, and that we do not really care about the value of $x$. However, as I read from the book, we still apply some certain constriants to $x$, for example, when we are evaluating geometric series, we assume that $|x|<1$ even though we do not really care what value x is exactly. What I am trying to find here is that why is it allowed to use such a trick.

Comment: You can use any trick you like; all you're doing is manipulating symbols. However, it is only when you care to evaluate the series for some $x$ that convergence matters. It's been a while since I've read through that text, but I don't think Wilf goes on to actually evaluate the series at $x=\frac{1}{r}$, does he? If not, then it's a no-harm-no-foul situation

Comment: No, he doesn't. But when he is simplifying the RHS, I find that he is assuming that: $\frac{1-rx}{1-jx}a_j=0$ where $j\ne r$. And $\frac{1-rx}{1-rx}a_r\ne 0$. I found this very similar to the concept of limits that when $x$ tends to $r$, $a_j$ tends to the formula that we are looking for. not sure if I am going the right direction.